# USB keyboard not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, usb, keyboard

Yesterday I upgraded to **Ubuntu 12.04**, upon the upgrade completing my *USB* keyboard would not work. My *USB* mouse works fine and I have tried 3 different keyboards in all of my *USB* ports as well as a *PS2* keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

May be I can Help you! (I hope)
Try this general ways they might help U out:

- Updates Check
- Connect Ur Keyboard after Ur System fully starts and not before BOOT
- Search for any Additional Drivers (`System Settings` -> `Additional Drivers`)
- If above not works just try any another **USB** hardware in that **port** to check although that **port** is working or not! (i.e. **Pendrive**, **Mobile Device** etc)

Comment: I've tried all of the above suggestions, other than searching for additional drivers as I cannot do anything on my computer. The only thing that it displays once it has booted is the "Enter password to unlock your login keyring" window.

Comment: I bet there's a script you can run at startup that will recheck all usb ports.

Comment: So tell dat Script to this guy na! But Hey U cheked that Port is working properly kya? Try **Safe Mode** it might help!